# Sound notification push direct to my users

Tags: php, audio, joomla, notifications

This question is not a 'do it for me question' I have spend ages and ages on google trying to find a solution or service

I am basically trying to create a notification on my website that I can push to the server and play to my users as and when I need to alert them,

I have a website where my users will react when I have posted information and I need to alert them with sound increasing their reaction time.

Im using a Joomla 3.2.3 based website

Comment: do you need help with the alert sound or the push functionality?

Comment: Well firstly, have you got the message working that shows when you have posted any information? If not, then what sort of information are you referring to? Article, forum posts, shouts? Any of this will require Ajax which won't exactly be an easy task, but is still doable. Once you have the Ajax message dealt with, the sound will be easy enough. Start coming up with some code and re-add it to your question

Answer (score 0):

This is previously dicussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594425/ajax-push-system) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138309/php-ajax-jquery-server-push-system)

I think it is probably most viable to write an ajax-based module that query the server every X seconds, and pop up notifications if there are any. Using websockets is probably a lot more work,

regards Jonas